How to calculate this improper integral?
How to calculate the Integral involving MarcumQ function whose Integral interval is (0, +Infinity)?
Any help (code or reference) would be greatly appreciated.
Integrate[(MarcumQ[
     1, ((1 + q)   Sqrt[((1 + q^2)   x)/\[Omega]])/(2   q), 
     Sqrt[((-1 + q)^2   (1 + q^2)   x)/\[Omega]]/(2   q)] - 
    MarcumQ[1, 
     Sqrt[((-1 + q)^2   (1 + q^2)   x)/\[Omega]]/(2   q), ((1 + 
          q)   Sqrt[((1 + q^2)   x)/\[Omega]])/(2   q)])*Exp[-varq*x]*
  x^(varp - 1), {x, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {0 <= q <= 1, 0 <= varp <= 1, 
   0 <= varq <= 1, \[Omega] > 0}]


Related:

Solutions to Integrals Involving the Marcum Q−Function and Applications
Integral involving exponential and Marcum-Q function

     
     
     

Maybe exist closed-form, but I didn't find it.
If we simplify a bit we have to solve:
LaplaceTransform[x^(-1 + varp) *(MarcumQ[1, Sqrt[x]*a1, Sqrt[x]*b1] - MarcumQ[1, Sqrt[x]*a2, Sqrt[x]*b2]), x, varq]

I will deal with the first term because the second one is similar, but the parameters are different.
LaplaceTransform[x^(-1 + varp)*MarcumQ[1, Sqrt[x]*a1, Sqrt[x]*b1], x, varq]

 (*Where : a1=((1 + q)  Sqrt[(1 + q^2) /ω])/(2 q), b1=Sqrt[((-1 + q)^2 (1 + q^2))/ω]/(2 q)*)

After tedious calculations I have only:
$$\mathcal{L}_x\left[x^{-1+\text{varp}} \left(Q_1\left(\frac{\sqrt{x} \left((1+q) \sqrt{\frac{1+q^2}{\omega }}\right)}{2 q},\frac{\sqrt{x} \sqrt{\frac{(-1+q)^2 \left(1+q^2\right)}{\omega
   }}}{2 q}\right)-Q_1\left(\frac{\sqrt{x} \sqrt{\frac{(-1+q)^2 \left(1+q^2\right)}{\omega }}}{2 q},\frac{\sqrt{x} \left((1+q) \sqrt{\frac{1+q^2}{\omega }}\right)}{2
   q}\right)\right)\right](\text{varq})=\\-\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{8^{\text{varp}} (-1+q)^{-2 (k+\text{varp})} q^{2 \text{varp}} (1+q)^{-2 (k+\text{varp})+2 (2 k+\text{varp})}
   \left(1+q^2\right)^{-\text{varp}} \omega ^{\text{varp}} \Gamma (k+\text{varp}) \Gamma (1+2 k+\text{varp}) \, _2\tilde{F}_1\left(k+\text{varp},1+2
   k+\text{varp};1+k+\text{varp};-\frac{(1+q)^2 \left(1+q^2\right)+8 q^2 \text{varq} \omega }{(-1+q)^2 \left(1+q^2\right)}\right)}{\Gamma (1+k)^2}-\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }
   \frac{8^{\text{varp}} (-1+q)^{-2 (k+\text{varp})+2 (2 k+\text{varp})} q^{2 \text{varp}} (1+q)^{-2 (k+\text{varp})} \left(1+q^2\right)^{-\text{varp}} \omega ^{\text{varp}} \Gamma
   (k+\text{varp}) \Gamma (1+2 k+\text{varp}) \, _2\tilde{F}_1\left(k+\text{varp},1+2 k+\text{varp};1+k+\text{varp};-\frac{(-1+q)^2 \left(1+q^2\right)+8 q^2 \text{varq} \omega
   }{(1+q)^2 \left(1+q^2\right)}\right)}{\Gamma (1+k)^2}$$
q = 1/2; varp = 1/2; varq = 1/2; ω = Pi; M = 50;

-Sum[(8^varp (-1 + q)^(-2 (k + varp)) q^(
 2 varp) (1 + q)^(-2 (k + varp) + 
  2 (2 k + varp)) (1 + q^2)^-varp ω^
 varp Gamma[k + varp] Gamma[
  1 + 2 k + varp] Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[k + varp, 
  1 + 2 k + varp, 
  1 + k + varp, -(((1 + q)^2 (1 + q^2) + 
    8 q^2 varq ω)/((-1 + q)^2 (1 + q^2)))])/
Gamma[1 + k]^2, {k, 0, M}] - 
Sum[1/Gamma[1 + k]^2 8^
varp  (-1 + q)^(-2 (k + varp) + 2 (2 k + varp))  q^(
2 varp)  (1 + q)^(-2 (k + varp))  (1 + q^2)^-varp  ω^
varp  Gamma[k + varp]  Gamma[
 1 + 2 k + varp]  Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[k + varp, 
 1 + 2 k + varp, 
 1 + k + varp, -(((-1 + q)^2 (1 + q^2) + 
   8 q^2 varq ω)/((1 + q)^2 (1 + q^2)))], {k, 0, M}] // N

(*0.60433*)

EDITED 18.06.2024
MarcumQ has the series form:
$$Q_1\left(\text{a1} \sqrt{x},\text{b1} \sqrt{x}\right)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \left(\frac{\text{a1}}{\text{b1}}\right)^n e^{\frac{1}{2} \left(-\text{a1}^2 x-\text{b1}^2 x\right)}
   I_n(\text{a1} \text{b1} x)$$
LaplaceTransform[x^(-1 + varp)*(a1/b1)^n E^(1/2 (-a1^2 x - b1^2 x))
BesselI[n, a1 b1 x], x, varq]
(*Piecewise expression*)   

Only with this condition: $\left| \frac{\left(-1+q^4\right)^2}{\left(1+q^4+q^2 (2+4 \text{varq} \omega )\right)^2}\right| <1$ is True, we can check:
Resolve[Exists[{q, varq , ω}, Abs[(-1 + q^4)^2/(1 + q^4 + q^2 (2 + 4 varq ω))^2] < 1 && 
0 <= q <= 1 && 0 <= varq <= 1 && ω > 0]]
(*True*)

a bit of manipulation series:
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{2^{\text{varp}} \left(\frac{\text{a1}}{\text{b1}}\right)^n \left(\frac{\text{a1}^2 \text{b1}^2}{\left(\text{a1}^2+\text{b1}^2+2
   \text{varq}\right)^2}\right)^{n/2} \left(\text{a1}^2+\text{b1}^2+2 \text{varq}\right)^{-\text{varp}} \Gamma (n+\text{varp}) \, _2F_1\left(\frac{n+\text{varp}}{2},\frac{1}{2}
   (1+n+\text{varp});1+n;\frac{4 \text{a1}^2 \text{b1}^2}{\left(\text{a1}^2+\text{b1}^2+2 \text{varq}\right)^2}\right)}{\Gamma (1+n)}=\\\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{2^{\text{varp}}
   \left(\frac{\text{a1}}{\text{b1}}\right)^n \left(\frac{\text{a1}^2 \text{b1}^2}{\left(\text{a1}^2+\text{b1}^2+2 \text{varq}\right)^2}\right)^{n/2} \left(\text{a1}^2+\text{b1}^2+2
   \text{varq}\right)^{-\text{varp}} \Gamma (n+\text{varp}) \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(\frac{\text{a1}^2 \text{b1}^2}{\left(\text{a1}^2+\text{b1}^2+2
   \text{varq}\right)^2}\right)^m \Gamma (1+n) \Gamma (n+2 m+\text{varp})}{\Gamma (1+m) \Gamma (1+n+m) \Gamma (n+\text{varp})}}{\Gamma (1+n)}=\\\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \sum _{m=0}^{\infty }
   \frac{2^{\text{varp}} \left(\frac{\text{a1}}{\text{b1}}\right)^n \left(\frac{\text{a1}^2 \text{b1}^2}{\left(\text{a1}^2+\text{b1}^2+2 \text{varq}\right)^2}\right)^{m+\frac{n}{2}}
   \left(\text{a1}^2+\text{b1}^2+2 \text{varq}\right)^{-\text{varp}} \Gamma (2 m+n+\text{varp})}{\Gamma (1+m) \Gamma (1+m+n)}$$
where: $\text{a1}=\frac{(1+q) \sqrt{\frac{1+q^2}{\omega }}}{2 q}$ and $\text{b1}=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{(-1+q)^2 \left(1+q^2\right)}{\omega }}}{2 q}$
Putting all together:
$$\int_0^{\infty } \left(Q_1\left(\frac{(1+q) \sqrt{\frac{\left(1+q^2\right) x}{\omega }}}{2 q},\frac{\sqrt{\frac{(-1+q)^2 \left(1+q^2\right) x}{\omega }}}{2
   q}\right)-Q_1\left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{(-1+q)^2 \left(1+q^2\right) x}{\omega }}}{2 q},\frac{(1+q) \sqrt{\frac{\left(1+q^2\right) x}{\omega }}}{2 q}\right)\right) \exp (-\text{varq} x)
   x^{\text{varp}-1} \, dx=\\\left(\text{varq}+\frac{\left(1+q^2\right)^2}{4 q^2 \omega }\right)^{-\text{varp}} \Gamma (\text{varp}) \left(\underset{m=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum
   }}\underset{n=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\frac{2^{-2 m-n} \left(\frac{(1+q) \sqrt{\frac{1+q^2}{\omega }} \sqrt{\frac{\left(-1+q^4\right)^2}{\left(1+q^4+q^2 (2+4 \text{varq} \omega
   )\right)^2}}}{\sqrt{\frac{(-1+q)^2 \left(1+q^2\right)}{\omega }}}\right)^n \left(\frac{\left(-1+q^4\right)^2}{\left(1+q^4+q^2 (2+4 \text{varq} \omega )\right)^2}\right)^m \Gamma (2
   m+n+\text{varp})}{\Gamma (1+m) \Gamma (1+m+n) \Gamma (\text{varp})}-\underset{m=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\underset{n=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\frac{2^{-2 m-n}
   \left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{(-1+q)^2 \left(1+q^2\right)}{\omega }} \sqrt{\frac{\left(-1+q^4\right)^2}{\left(1+q^4+q^2 (2+4 \text{varq} \omega )\right)^2}}}{(1+q) \sqrt{\frac{1+q^2}{\omega
   }}}\right)^n \left(\frac{\left(-1+q^4\right)^2}{\left(1+q^4+q^2 (2+4 \text{varq} \omega )\right)^2}\right)^m \Gamma (2 m+n+\text{varp})}{\Gamma (1+m) \Gamma (1+m+n) \Gamma
   (\text{varp})}\right)=\\2^{\text{varp}} \left(2 \text{varq}+\frac{\left(1+q^2\right)^2}{2 q^2 \omega }\right)^{-\text{varp}} \Gamma (\text{varp}) \left(\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \sum _{n=0}^{\infty }
   \frac{(\text{varp})_{2 m+n} (1)_n \left(\frac{\left(-1+q^4\right)^2}{4 \left(1+q^4+q^2 (2+4 \text{varq} \omega )\right)^2}\right)^m \left(\frac{(1+q)^2 \left(1+q^2\right)}{2+2 q^2
   \left(2+q^2+4 \text{varq} \omega \right)}\right)^n}{(1)_{m+n} (m! n!)}-\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(\text{varp})_{2 m+n} (1)_n
   \left(\frac{\left(-1+q^4\right)^2}{4 \left(1+q^4+q^2 (2+4 \text{varq} \omega )\right)^2}\right)^m \left(\frac{(-1+q)^2 \left(1+q^2\right)}{2+2 q^2 \left(2+q^2+4 \text{varq} \omega
   \right)}\right)^n}{(1)_{m+n} (m! n!)}\right)=\\-4^{\text{varp}} \left(\frac{q^2 \omega }{1+q^4+q^2 (2+4 \text{varq} \omega )}\right)^{\text{varp}} \Gamma (\text{varp})
   \left(\text{H3}\left(\text{varp},1,1,\frac{\left(-1+q^4\right)^2}{4 \left(1+q^4+q^2 (2+4 \text{varq} \omega )\right)^2},\frac{(-1+q)^2 \left(1+q^2\right)}{2+2 q^2 \left(2+q^2+4
   \text{varq} \omega \right)}\right)-\text{H3}\left(\text{varp},1,1,\frac{\left(-1+q^4\right)^2}{4 \left(1+q^4+q^2 (2+4 \text{varq} \omega )\right)^2},\frac{(1+q)^2
   \left(1+q^2\right)}{2+2 q^2 \left(2+q^2+4 \text{varq} \omega \right)}\right)\right)$$
where: $H3$ is Horn function and it can be expressed by Srivastava-Daoust function.
q = 1/2; varp = 1/2; varq = 1/2; ω = Pi; M = 50;

F[q_, varp_, varq_, ω_] := 2^varp*(2 varq + (1 + q^2)^2/(2 q^2 ω))^-varp*Gamma[varp]*(Sum[
  Pochhammer[varp, 2 m + n]/Pochhammer[1, m + n]*
   Pochhammer[1, n]/(
   m! n!)*((-1 + q^4)^2/(
    4 (1 + q^4 + q^2 (2 + 4 varq ω))^2))^
   m*(((1 + q)^2 (1 + q^2))/(
     2 + 2 q^2 (2 + q^2 + 4 varq ω)))^n, {m, 0, M}, {n,0, 
   M}] - Sum[Pochhammer[varp, 2 m + n]/Pochhammer[1, m + n]*
   Pochhammer[1, n]/(
   m! n!)*((-1 + q^4)^2/(
    4 (1 + q^4 + q^2 (2 + 4 varq ω))^2))^
   m*(((-1 + q)^2 (1 + q^2))/(
     2 + 2 q^2 (2 + q^2 + 4 varq ω)))^n, {m, 0, M}, {n,0, M}]);

  F[q, varp, varq, ω] // N

  (*0.60433*)


Thank you for your answer! Can the expression be more simplified using MeijerG or FoxH? Is it possible?

I post a answer update  in near time . Solution can be expressed by Horn function H3 ( 11 on the list) https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HornFunction.html.

@138Aspen . Can H3 Horn functions be simplified? I don't know.

Sacred cows give little milk (Stanisław Jerzy Lec).
q = 1/2; varp = 1/2; varq = 1/2; \[Omega] = Pi; NIntegrate[(MarcumQ[
 1, ((1 + q)    Sqrt[((1 + q^2)    x)/\[Omega]])/(2    q), 
 Sqrt[((-1 + q)^2    (1 + q^2)    x)/\[Omega]]/(2    q)] - 
MarcumQ[1, 
 Sqrt[((-1 + q)^2    (1 + q^2)    x)/\[Omega]]/(2    q), ((1 + 
      q)    Sqrt[((1 + q^2)    x)/\[Omega]])/(2    q)])*
  Exp[-varq*x]*x^(varp - 1), {x, 0, Infinity}]


0.60433

